# $N=1!+2\cdot 2!+3\cdot 3!+...+2017\cdot 2017!$ How many consecutive $9$ are there at the end of this number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, factorial

$N=1!+2\cdot 2!+3\cdot 3!+...+2017\cdot 2017!$ 
How many consecutive $9$ are there at the end of $N$?

I can't even understand why will there be nines at the end.
I think maybe N can be represented as 
$X\cdot10^n-1$.
 Appreciate for any hint or clue. I will try to work it out.

Comment: Hint: $k\cdot k!=(k+1)!-k!$

Comment: Do you know howto find the number of $0$'s at the end of $n!$?

Comment: cf. [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: @Atticus thank you very much , now I knowhow to do it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes I do, thanks.

Comment: The FAQ encourages you to write up the solution if the hints are sufficient.  After a couple days you can accept it.  I find writing it up solidifies my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can transform the series into a telescoping sum.

Using the fact that:
 $k\cdot k!=(k+1)!-k!$

$1+2\cdot 2! +3\cdot 3! +...+2017\cdot 2017! = 2018!-1!$

Now we need to find the number of trailing 0s in 2018!
This is the same as finding the largest value of $k$ such that $10^k|2018!$.

$10=2\cdot 5$

$2^{10}=1024$ and $5^4=625$
2s dominate 5s, so in order to find number of pairs of $(2,5)$ we need to count number of 5s

$k=\lfloor(2018/5) \rfloor +\lfloor(2018/25) \rfloor +\lfloor (2018/125)\rfloor+\lfloor(2018/625)\rfloor=403+80+16+3$

$k=502$

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got after the hint.
Since k*k!=(k+1)!-k!, N=(2!-1!)+(3!-2!)+(4!-3!)...(2018!-2017!)=2018!-1.
For 2018! , there must be more 2 factors than 5, so I only need to calculate 5.
2018/5=403...3
2018/25=80...18
2018/125=16...18
2018/625=3...143
So there are 403+80+16+3=502 zeros at the end.So there are 502 nines at the end.